# "Object mapping could not be found for Type with identity" Exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I use EF 4.1 with POCO. 
Entities with edmx are located in a separate assembly.

When I call:

```
var key = new EntityKey("MyEntities.Vendors", "Id", vendorId);
if (ctx.TryGetObjectByKey(key, out vendor)) ...
```

Exception is thrown "Object mapping could not be found for Type with identity"

As far as I understand EF looks for Vendor in the calling assembly and can not find it there.
So it should be the way of telling the context where to search types, but I have no idea which one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ctx.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(assembly);
```

before TryGetObjectByKey works fine.

'aseembly' is the assembly where model classes live.

Comment: in the context.cs file: 
 ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(GetFlattenedProductList_Result)));